# Image forcing down list CSS

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/gxLt5/

HTML

```
    <nav class="header">
        <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" height="32" width="42">
    <ul class="navigation">
            <li id="a" class=""><a
                    href="#"><span></span>A</a></li>
            <li id="b" class=""><a
                    href="#"><span></span>B</a></li>
        <li id="account" class="right">
            <a href="/admin/profile"><span></span>Test Test</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="/users/logout">Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

When I've added the image in the top it pushed down the list out of view. How can I make it so I have my image to the left of the list and still have the list shown on the right of it.

Comment: `ul` has `display:block` by default, so it jumps to the new line, you can use `display:inline-block` to fix the issue, using floating is also a good approach. http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/gxLt5/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following css;

```
.header img {
    float:left
}
.header .navigation {
    float:left;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EjrGU/)